# ElasticSearch - Problem with filter on Boolean query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I have a problem with filter in boolean query.

I want to apply a filter based on 3 fields with 1 minimum filter match :

```
$params = [
    'from' => 0,
    'size' => 25,
    'index' => 'document',
    'body' => [
        'query' => [
            'bool' => [
                'filter' => [
                    'bool' => [
                        'minimum_should_match' => 1,
                        'should' => [
                            'term' => [
                                'VISIBILITE' => 'T'
                            ],
                            'term' => [
                                'ECRITURE' => 'M'
                            ],
                            'term' => [
                                'LECTURE' => 'M'
                            ],
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                'must' => [
                    [
                        'bool' => [
                            'should' => [ 
                                [
                                    'match' => [
                                        'OBJET' => $recherche,
                                    ]
                                ],
                            ] 
                        ]
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

I get no result with this query, however i see lots of relevant documents in index.

---

Opster Elasticsearch Ninja test:

For example 1 that you proposed to me, I have many results that are returned.

However, when I want to perform a must query on the OBJECT field, I don't get the same result with the filter matching perfectly.

Here is an example :

1. Search with the must clause only

```
{
    "took": 8,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 2,
        "successful": 2,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 1268,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 13.616098,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "document",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "26685",
                "_score": 13.616098,
                "_source": {
                    "NUMDOCUMENT": "26685",
                    "TYPEDOCUMENT": "Proc\u00e9dure",
                    "OBJET": "Proc\u00e9dure d'importation des index dans Marco 2",
                    "MOTCLES": "",
                    "LECTURE": "S",
                    "VISIBILITE": "T", // Must match on second search
                    "ECRITURE": "M" // Must match on second search
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

2. Search with must clause and filter

```
{
    "took": 9,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 2,
        "successful": 2,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 10000,
            "relation": "gte"
        },
        "max_score": 0,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "document",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "431",
                "_score": 0,
                "_source": {
                    "NUMDOCUMENT": "431",
                    "TYPEDOCUMENT": "Document",
                    "OBJET": "Diagnostic informatique SAFC",
                    "LECTURE": "M",
                    "VISIBILITE": "T",
                    "ECRITURE": "M"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

It is no longer the same document that appears first (although the document corresponds to the filter). It's as if the search filter influences the score and relevance of the search must.

Comment: Mind sharing a few of those docs + your index mapping?

Comment: does it work without `must` part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I forgot a hook in should filter.

**Not good :**

```
'bool' => [
                'filter' => [
                    'bool' => [
                        'minimum_should_match' => 1,
                        'should' => [
                            'term' => [
                                'VISIBILITE' => 'T'
                            ],
                            'term' => [
                                'ECRITURE' => 'M'
                            ],
                            'term' => [
                                'LECTURE' => 'M'
                            ],
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
```

**Good :**

```
'bool' => [
                'filter' => [
                    'bool' => [
                        'minimum_should_match' => 1,
                        'should' => [[ // Double hook
                            'term' => [
                                'VISIBILITE' => 'T'
                            ],
                            'term' => [
                                'ECRITURE' => 'M'
                            ],
                            'term' => [
                                'LECTURE' => 'M'
                            ],
                        ]]
                    ]
                    
                ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue seems to be with your `bool` query, if you look at your query at top level you have two construct

1. Filter block which is having 3 should conditions, out of which at least 1 should match, and this would filter ie reduce the document set on which your next `must` clause would be executed.
2. Must block, I suspect not matching anything on the reduced document set from step-1, which is causing your query to return nothing.

In order to debug the issue, you should try the first block independently and later on merge to see if you are getting a result or not, as your `must` block doesn't have proper data, I've created below sample which shows if you have proper data, it returns the data:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "VISIBILITE": "T"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "ECRITURE": "T"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "LECTURE": "T"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1
        }
    }
}
```

**And search query result , which shows the `_source` of matching docs**

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "minshouldmatch",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 1.5686158,
                "_source": {
                    "VISIBILITE": "T", 
                    "ECRITURE": "T",
                    "LECTURE": "T"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "minshouldmatch",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.18232156,
                "_source": {
                    "VISIBILITE": "T", // note even only 1 condition matches still it comes in SR
                    "ECRITURE": "M",
                    "LECTURE": "M"
                }
            }
        ]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply ! I added a test and an explanation after my previous request.